# Getting full info for an Exchange Category via EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, categories, exchangewebservices, outlook-2010

I have a user's info in the form of an ExchangeService object and need to get the Categories for each email, contact, etc as I pull a user's information in. Alas, the following gets me only strings:

```
... bla bla setup ExchangeServices.Contact exContact = ... ;
var cats = exContact.Categories;
```

But what I'd really like are full on objects of some sort, with (minimally) RGB values for the actual color. "Red", "Orange", and "DarkSteel" are just not super useful, and when there are user-defined categories it's even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get list of available categories in order to get color and other category properties. We need the same methods implemented here http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/getcategories.html

Comment: This seems good, but I'm definitely not looking for a proprietary 4th/5th party solution here. I'll take a look at this company's offerings though, so thanks.